# Contextual action mode remove side bars onClick() : webview

Tags: android, webview, contextual-action-bar, actionmode

I'm trying to hide sidebars that we usually see on selecting any text on webview, look at the image below:
i want to hide these blue bars of selected text as its overlapping with my framelayout(invisible) currently.

[image]

Comment: here is no image

Comment: please check now.